# __next_prime symbol undefined

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, std

I am including unordered_map in a XCode project for iOS. Originally when I tried linking I got errors for new and delete operations, but when I added "-lstdc++" to "Other Linker Flags" those go away, but I am left with the following missing symbol.

```
"std::__1::__next_prime(unsigned long)", referenced from:
```

I tried different combinations of C++ Standard Language/Dialect but cannot get this to go away.

Any idea what library includes this?

Thanks!

Comment: This symbol is largely suspicious of being a private function of the C++ standard library.

Comment: (For which you get a +1 from me, I have literally no idea what's wrong... Maybe a mismatching stdlib version? Linker bug? Whatever...)

Comment: Normally if you were compiling C++ code, the C++ library would be linked for you by the compiler.  How are you invoking the toolchain to get to this point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function is a private method in LLVM's `libc++`: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libcpp/libcpp-31/src/hash.cpp?txt. Therefore, you need to change your **C++ Standard Library** to **libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)**, or change your linker flag to `-lc++`.

Comment: (Note that, in general, you should avoid adding the standard library to the link flags yourself. XCode has an option specifically to choose the runtime library, as long as you set up the compiler choice correctly.)