# Vuforia VideoPlayback example for 4.0?

Tags: ios, vuforia

Has anyone successfully ported Vuforia's 3.x VideoPlayback sample code to run under the new 4.0 libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this wasn't as hard as I thought.

1. follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279681/next-prime-symbol-undefined) to change the C++ library
2. remove your libQCAR.a and headers in your build folders and replace it with libVuforia.a and headers
3. change your build targets to include arm64 and standard architectures (you'll see it)
4. search/replace all instances of ImageTracker with ObjectTarget
5. change targetPositiveDimensions from Vec2F to Vec3F
6. get an app key from Vuforia (on their web site), look for QCAR::setInitParameters, and add a second parameter with that key as a string...

   QCAR::setInitParameters(mQCARInitFlags, "my license key");

I have a few lingering issues, but most of it is working. The time needed to start up the tracker is much longer than older versions, AFAICT.