# Getting build error in iOS project after adding Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I just started a new project with latest react-native(0.33.0). which was running fine.

I added cocoapods in iOS project after that I'm getting build error. here is the screenshot of error.

[image: error log]

There is no native libs in project as of now, I don't why this error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was Other linker flag, Other linker flag was blank, I had to set it to -lc++ and it worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279822/2009703

Answer (score 0):

Set "iOS Deployment Target" in Pods project to the same value as used in your project and check that "Build Active Architecture Only" flags are the same for the projects.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Though error was related to linker flag http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279822/2009703